# Sharepoint 2010 Violating cross-domain restrictions and infopath

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, infopath-data-connections

Hello I created a form in infopath and when i go to load it up via sharepoints front end I get this error message

"A query to retrieve form data cannot be completed because this action would violate cross-domain restrictions. "

Now contrary to what it says, Cross domain is enabled for infopath and I have already saved the connection as a udc file on the data connection library in sharepoint and have tried many different solutions I found online to no avail.  Please help.

Comment: I also have the same issue and going into CA and Allowing cross-domain data access did not work for me. I'm trying to Attach to the UserProfile Service so my InfoPath form pulls back the username of the individual accessing the form. I have tried all of the above and have returned no positive results.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this has already been answered: [InfoPath Form and Web Service (would violate cross-domain restrictions)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51275/infopath-form-and-web-service-would-violate-cross-domain-restrictions) Are you using Office 365?

[Also take a look at this article](http://www.sharepointed.com/2012/11/08/a-query-to-retrieve-form-data-cannot-be-completed-because-this-action-would-violate-cross-domain-restrictions/). It discusses a solution for this issue (in a SharePoint install, not office 365):

> Fix:
>   Update the InfoPath Form Services settings in Central Admin
>   Central Admin –> General Application Settings –> Configure InfoPath Form Services
>   Cross-Domain Access for User Form Templates
>
> `http://CA-ADDRESS/_admin/ipfsConfig.aspx`

Comment: I've enabled Cross domain access before and I have already tried using udcx files in a connection library.  I tried following the post and tutorials on code signing and full trust but those options arent available for me for whatever reason.